# Pass variable into Object.keys() or Object.values()

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a problem with creating a dynamic "string" passed intp Object.values()

```
import data from "~/static/words.json"
console.log(Object.values(data.vocabulary.lection1)) //This works
let section = "vocabulary"
let lection = "lection1"
let string = `data.${section}.${lection}`
console.log(Object.values(string)) //This doesn't work, It returns ["d", "a", "t", "a", ".", "v", "o", "c", "a", "b", "u", "l", "a", "r", "y", ".", "l", "e", "c", "t", "i", "o", "n", "1"]
```

Comment: You can use `Object.values(data[section][lection])`. The code you have is not how JavaScript works.

Comment: @Pointy But there is a problem, I got this error. Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type.

Comment: @devMontu that is a TypeScript error.

Comment: @VLAZ so how can i fix that? I cant?

Comment: @devMontu use a type guard or an assertion, if needed. I neither know your data, nor the types you're working with, so I cannot really be specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're turning it all into a string then breaking it down into an array by misuing `Object.values()`. This is likely what you're looking for:

UPDATED after additional info:

```js
const data = { vocabulary: { lection1: { hello: 'helllo' } } };
console.log(Object.values(data.vocabulary.lection1)); //This works
let section = 'vocabulary';
let lection = 'lection1';
let string = `data.${section}.${lection}`;
const otherString = data[section][lection];
// console.log(Object.values(string));
console.log(Object.values(otherString));
```

Comment: But there is a problem, I got this error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type.

Comment: what does your `data` variable look like then?

Comment: ``` "vocabulary": {
        "lection1": {
            "hello":"helllo"}}```

Comment: Integrated my solution into your example. If you run the snippet, it works.

Comment: Ahh yea, thats it. Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you you are passing a string literal into `Object.values()`.

As you can see [on the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), `Object.values()` takes an iterable (a string, for example, is an iterable list of characters) and splits it into an array.

The issue is that you are trying to *access* the value of an object, but you aren't referencing the accessed dictionary whatsoever, just a String. In fact, Object.values() is not needed whatsoever in this case.

You can access the values of an object in two ways.

`data.section.lection1` is one option, where section and lection are *key names* in the object. This is not dynamic, however useful to know. The other way, which is more likely what you're looking for, is `data[selection][lection]` where selection and lection are *variables* representing strings that are valid keys in the Object (or the corresponding type for the keys).

Here's a fiddle I made for it: https://jsfiddle.net/isaackogan/p1dxknwg/1/

Answer (score 0):

Object.values() return the values of an object as a two dimensional array

```
let sampleObject = { a: 'ab', b: 'ba'}
console.log(Object.values(sampleObject)) // ['ab', 'ba']
```

Now, String also behaves like an object in JS. So, when you passed the string in Object.values it returned the array of characters that makes up the string.

Give the documentation a shot: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values